# compare students with overloaded < operator

Tags: c++, c++11

this is the string to compare, lastname+firstName and id
comp is public, my sort method does not work, I am not able to find where the code fails, I am supposed to have the students listed in the order

```
comp=new char[strlen(lName)+strlen(fName)+strlen(id)+1];
```

this is my student constructor:

```
Student::Student(char * first, char * last, char *i,char * stand, int credit, double g, Date * d, Date * matricDate){
        lName=last;
        fName=first;
        id=i;
        standing=stand;
        credits=credit;
        gpa=g;
        dob=d;
        matDate=matricDate;
        comp=new char[strlen(lName)+strlen(fName)+strlen(id)+1];
        sprintf(comp,"%s%s%s",lName,fName,id);
};
```

this is the operator I overload

```
 bool Student::operator<(const Student &second){
                if(comp<second.comp){
                        return true;
                }else{
                        return false;
                }
        };
```

I have the student list as:

```
 vector<Student *> roster_list;
```

I add student like this:

```
void Roster::addStudent(Student *student){

        roster_list.push_back(student); 

        };
```

here is my sort:

```
void Roster::mySort(){
        sort(roster_list.begin(),roster_list.end());
};
```

my main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Roster.cpp"
#include "Date.cpp"
#include "Student.cpp"

using namespace std;


int main(){

        Roster *r=new Roster();
        Date *d=new Date(12,05,1987);
        Student *st=new Student("Jason", "Sam", "124542", "sophomore", 34, 4.0, d,d);
        Student *st2=new Student("Ahmad", "Khan", "23452", "freshman", 34, 4.0, d,d);

        Student *st3=new Student("Selam", "Can", "23431", "freshman", 34, 3.0, d,d);
        Student *st4=new Student("Andrew", "Rosenberg", "34523", "Senior", 34, 4.0, d,d);
        Student *st5=new Student("Selam", "Can", "23431", "freshman", 34, 3.0, d,d);


        r->addStudent(st);
        r->addStudent(st2);
        r->addStudent(st3);
        r->addStudent(st4);

        // Student 3 and 5 are same 
        // == operator check
        if(*st3==*st5){
                cout<<"Students are same \n";
        }

        // != overloading operator check
        if(*st3!=*st4){
                cout<<"Students are different\n";
        }

        cout<<"################Before Sorting###############\n";
        r->toString();
        cout<<"################After Sorting###############\n";
        r->mySort();
        r->toString();



        cout<<"\n"<<st->getComp();
        cout<<"\n"<<st3->getComp();

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Students are same 
Students are different
################Before Sorting###############
Student Info:Jason      Sam     124542  sophomore       4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Ahmad      Khan    23452   freshman        4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Selam      Can     23431   freshman        3
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Andrew     Rosenberg       34523   Senior  4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
################After Sorting###############
Student Info:Jason      Sam     124542  sophomore       4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Ahmad      Khan    23452   freshman        4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Selam      Can     23431   freshman        3
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987
Student Info:Andrew     Rosenberg       34523   Senior  4
Birth Date: December 5, 1987
Matric Date: December 5, 1987

SamJason124542
CanSelam23431
```

I tried this

```
bool StudentSort(Student* lhs, Student* rhs) {
    return (*lhs)<(*rhs);
}



void Roster::mySort(){
        sort(roster_list.begin(),roster_list.end(),StudentSort);
};
```

still does not work, I get compilation error I have gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)

this is the error I get after this try:

```
Roster.cpp: In member function ‘void Roster::mySort()’:
Roster.cpp:69: error: argument of type ‘bool (Roster::)(Student*, Student*)’ does not match ‘bool (Roster::*)(Student*, Student*)’
```

Comment: Everywhere I look, there are pointers. I'm willing to bet none of those are necessary.

Comment: @chris This was pointed out the last time this code was posted. But they are worse than unnecessary, they are actually the cause of the OP's various problems.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have made `bool StudentSort` a member function of `Roster`. You should make it a non-member.

As an aside, you should make your `operator<` `const`, so it can operate on `const` references on both LHS and RHS. It doesn't make sense for a comparison operator to mutate an operand. You can also simplify it:

```
bool Student::operator<(const Student& second) const {
    return comp<second.comp;
}
```

With this in place, you can change your comparison function to take pointers to `const`:

```
bool StudentSort(const Student* lhs, const Student* rhs) { .... }
```

**Edit** As @RetiredNinja has pointer out, `Student::comp` is a `char*`, so your comparison operator is comparing pointers. This is quite unlikely to be what you want. The solution to this and most of your other problems is to **not use pointers at all**. Especially if you don't understand what they are. I suggest using an `std::string` for `comp`.

Comment: It looks like `comp` is just a char pointer.  I think the comparison function will need to do a bit more to work properly.

Comment: Makes me think the `==` and `!=` also compare pointers which will fall apart really quick when hardcoded literal strings aren't being used.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yeah, I think the whole thing is badly broken. I already suggested not using pointers last time OP posted this. That advice didn't seem to have any impact :/